# How to keep the vowel at the beginning of all the words in a string, but remove in the rest of the string

Tags: python-3.x

```
def shortenPlus(s) -> "s without some vowels":
    for char in s:
        if char in "AEIOUaeiou":
            return(s.replace(char,""))
```

I have the taken it out of the entire string. But I can't figure out how to restrict the replace function to everything but the first letter of each word in a string.

Comment: hope this solves your problem! http://stackoverflow.com/a/42142878/6840615

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, can you clarify, perhaps give a simple example? None of the words you have in your example start with vowels!

But here you could remove all the vowels in a word except the first vowel of the first word. Hard coded but gives you an idea:

```
s="without some vowels"
for char in s[2:]:
    if char in "AEIOUaeiou":
        s=s.replace(char,"")
print(s)
```

Outputs

```
witht sm vwls
```

Alternatively, to get the first char of every word, you could use a sentinel value that flags each time a non-alpha char such as punctuation or a space is present, then keeps the next char but not the others.

```
s="without some vowels"
sent=2
for char in s:
if sent>0:
    sent-=1
    print(char)
    continue
if not char.isalpha():
    sent=2
    continue
s=s.replace(char,"")
print(output)
```

Outputs

```
w s v
```

Comment: This is what it should return when executed. I need to define the function, not make a program that runs the function.                                                                                                         shortenPlus('What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow') == 'Wht is th arspd vlcty of an unldn swllw' s is inputted by the user, the "without some vowels" was just stating what the function was going to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
def shortenPlus(s):
    counter = 0 # accepted character count
    add_the_vowel = True     # check if vowel came for the first time for the word
    temp = " "  # temp string to store the output
    for letter in s:
        if letter == " ":
            add_the_vowel= True
        if add_the_vowel == True and letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            temp += s[counter]    # first vowel of the word
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            add_the_vowel = False    # restrict second vowel appeared
        else:
            temp += s[counter]
        counter += 1
    print(temp)
s = "without some vowels frienis"
shortenPlus(s)
```

> How to **keep the vowel at the beginning of all the words** in a string, but remove in the rest of the string

**output :**

witht som vowls frins